# SQL:Query to check if a column meets certain criteria, if it does perform one action if it doesn't perform another

Tags: sql, sqlcommand, join

I have found it quite hard to word what I want to do in the title so I will try my best to explain now!

I have two tables which I am using:

```
Master_Tab and Parts_Tab
```

Parts_Tab has the following information:

```
Order_Number | Completed| Part_Number|

   |    1       |     Y    |     64     |
   |    2       |     N    |     32     |
   |    3       |     Y    |     42     |
   |    1       |     N    |     32     |
   |    1       |     N    |     5      |
```

Master_Tab has the following information:

```
Order_Number|
 1           |  
 2           |
 3           |
 4           |
 5           |
```

I want to generate a query which will return ALL of the Order_Numbers listed in the Master_Tab on the following conditions...

For each Order_Number I want to check the Parts_Tab table to see if there are any parts which aren't complete (Completed = 'N'). For each Order_Number I then want  to count the number of uncompleted parts an order has against it. If an Order_Number does not have uncompleted parts or it is not in the Parts_Table then I want the count value to be 0.

So the table that would be generated would look like this:

```
Order_Number | Count_of_Non_Complete_Parts|
1            |            2               |
2            |            1               |
3            |            0               |
4            |            0               |
5            |            0               |
```

I was hoping that using a different kind of join on the tables would do this but I am clearly missing the trick!

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT mt.order_number, count(part_number) AS count_noncomplete_parts
FROM master_tab mt LEFT JOIN parts_tab pt
ON mt.order_number=pt.order_number AND pt.completed='N'
GROUP BY mt.order_number;
```

It is also possible to put `pt.completed='N'` into a WHERE clause, but you have to be careful of NULLs. Instead of the `AND` you can have

```
WHERE pt.completed='N' OR pr.completed IS NULL
```

Comment: Lazurus

Helloo, thanks for your quick response. I had originally done exactly this query but it only returns orders which have parts that are not completed in it. I want to return all orders. If the order has only parts which are complete (Completed = 'Y') Then the count of parts should be 0. Also if the order does not have any entries at all in the parts_tab then the count of parts should be 0.

Comment: @Tamara, Ummm, I tried this in Postgresql, and got the zeroes. If you use a `LEFT JOIN`, you _must_ get (at least) one row for every row in the master_tab. Are you sure you didn't have an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @LAzarus, Yep I just copied your code in and changed it to the table and field names just to check I hadn't done it wrong earlier. It returned exactly the same thing... I thought the left join would solve it but it didn't?! Confused.com

Comment: What db. Try `SELECT mt.order_number as m, pt.order_number as p FROM [left join]` and see how many rows you get. Make sure not to have a WHERE clause. That permits the outer join to cut down on rows.

Comment: Hey, I think that seems to work! I will double check that the data is correct with my system and let you know :). Thank you for now :)

Comment: Basically, if you have a `WHERE` clause that refers to the smaller side of an outer join (right side on a left join), you lose the outer join effect _unless_ you allow columns from that table to be NULL in the WHERE. So if you had another condition on parts that you took out of the post to simplify, that would mess up the outer join. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep it works like a dream. It's because I was using the where clause incorrectly! Thanks very much o smart one :)

Answer (score 2):

I have used `COALESCE` to convert NULL to zero where necessary. Depending on your database platform, you may need to use another method, e.g. `ISNULL` or `CASE`.

```
select mt.Order_Number, 
    coalesce(ptc.Count, 0) as Count_of_Non_Complete_Parts
from Master_Tab mt
left outer join (
    select Order_Number, count(*) as Count
    from Parts_Tab 
    where Completed = 'N'
    group by Order_Number
) ptc on mt.Order_Number = ptc.Order_Number
order by mt.Order_Number
```

Comment: `COALESCE` shouldn't be necessary for an `OUTER JOIN`. The count will be zero, not NULL. At least, in Postgresql.

Comment: @Andrew, the `COALESCE` covers the case where there is no matching row in the subquery, and thus `NULL` is returned.

Comment: You're right. I didn't think about the subquery case enough. Count itself will return zero, not NULL, but when you join to the subquery, you would just have a NULL. On the other hand, there is no need for a subquery for the OP. She just needs a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Heya, Thanks your response RedFilter... I think this is working too I will double check the data and let you know! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT mt.Order_Number SUM(tbl.Incomplete) Count_of_Non_Complete_Parts
FROM Master_Tab mt
    LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT Order_Number, CASE WHEN Completed = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Incomplete
       FROM Parts_Tab
     ) tbl on mt.Order_Number = tbl.Order_Number
GROUP BY mt.Order_Number
```

Add a `WHERE` clause to the outer query if you need to filter for specific order numbers.

Comment: You still want a `JOIN` I think to show orders from `Master` with no records in `Parts`

Comment: @JNK, I totally missed that requirment in the question... answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easiest to get a subquery in there. I think this should be self-explanitory, if not feel free to ask any questions.

```
CREATE TABLE #Parts
(
    Order_Number int,
    Completed char(1),
    Part_Number int
)

CREATE TABLE #Master
(
    Order_Number int
)

INSERT INTO #Parts
SELECT 1, 'Y', 64 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'N', 32 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Y', 42 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'N', 32 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'N', 5 

INSERT INTO #Master
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 6

SELECT M.Order_Number, ISNULL(Totals.NonCompletedCount, 0) FROM #Master M
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT P.Order_Number, COUNT(*) AS NonCompletedCount FROM #Parts P
                WHERE P.Completed = 'N'
                GROUP BY P.Order_Number) Totals ON Totals.Order_Number = M.Order_Number
```

Comment: Thanks for your response I appreciate the time you spent answering my question. Nice bit of code but it's not exactly what I was looking for unfortunately. I found a solution in one of the earlier responses which only is a small amendment to what I was doing. Thanks again though.